# How do I make a skyrim mod without creation kit?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I was always wondering how modders on the nexus make amazing mods without the creation kit. I don't even know how to use it.

I wanted to make my own race because alot of race mods don't really suit my interests so I wanted to make my own. Anyone know? (A playable race, not for a follower or something..)

Comment: Although I voted to close this question as off-topic, I would like to point out that the CK really isn't as scary as it seems -- especially when it comes to something like creating a new race. Here's [a page](http://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Tutorial_Creating_a_Playable_Race) that details exactly what you need to do to create a new race. If you want to add any custom meshes/textures, that's slightly more complicated, but there are still [some straightforward tutorials](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/Creating_a_custom_race_for_Skyrim) available.

Answer (score 4):

You can make some fairly simple mods using only [TES5Edit](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25859/?). You’re going to need that program for modding anyway, even if you use the Creation Kit.

If you start with someone else’s custom race mod and look at it in TES5Edit, you might be able to figure out how to make the edits you want for your own mod. I’ve never tried to make a custom race, so I don’t know how difficult it would be to do. Back before the Creation Kit was available, I think everyone made their mods that way (not sure about that though).

If your mod has custom textures or other files, you’ll need other programs to create those.

Comment: Thanks. But could it make a race with wings or horns or something?

Comment: @EmoFox In theory, it could make anything. I’d try downloading a mod that’s similar to what you want and see how they implemented it. Depending on how complicated it is, you might figure out how to do it just from looking at their ESP in TES5Edit. Or maybe it will look too complicated, and you’ll have to figure out how to do it in the Creation Kit, even though that program’s a pain. I made a new spell in TES5Edit once, but I don’t know how complicated a new race would be.